# Add event to Google's calendar in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I've found this official package: https://pub.dev/packages/googleapis#-readme-tab-

I'm looking to add events to Google's calendar but the plugin doesn't have too much information about it. It points to Google documentation but inside that link doesn't mention anything about Flutter or any examples.

Does anyone have some experience with this?

Answer (score 1):

Using `add_2_calendar` will add the event to Google's calendar directly:

```
final Event newEvent = Event(
        title: "title",
        description: "description",
        location: address,
        startDate: eventDate,
        endDate: eventDate.add(
          Duration(minutes: 30),
        ),
      );

      addEvent2Cal(newEvent);
```